# How to make a table of successive values

Tags: list-manipulation, iterators

I want a list, where each entry is of the form `{x,y}`. I want `x` to go from $-\pi / 2$ all the way up to $\pi/2$. I also want `y` to go from $-\pi / 2$ all the way up to $\pi/2$. I want everything to increment by, let's say, 1 for now (doesn't matter really). So here's what I want to end up with:

`{{-π/2,-π/2}, {-π/2,-π/2 + 1}, {-π/2,-π/2 + 2}, ..., {-π/2 + 1,-π/2}, {-π/2 + 1,-π/2 + 1}, {-π/2 + 1,-π/2 + 2}, ..., {-π/2 + 2,-π/2}, {-π/2 + 2,-π/2 + 1}, {-π/2 + 2,-π/2 + 2}, ...,{π/2,π/2}}`

I basically want to create a list of every possible pair of angles, where I can define the increment. I don't really know how I would do this.

Comment: I know it was just an example. The increments would be defined by $\pi / n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> basically want to create a list of every possible pair of angles

Make range, then use `Tuples` 2 at times ?

```
r = Range[-Pi/2, Pi/2, 1];
(Tuples[r, 2]) // N // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update**

```
r = Range[-Pi/2, Pi/2, Pi/3];
(c = Tuples[r, 2]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How would I go about including the final term of `{π/2,π/2}` in it?

Comment: @LonelyMathematician I made update. Need to use increment in terms of Pi (since Pi is irrational). I use Pi/3 increments.

Comment: thank you so much. Made my life easier, as now I am going to start trying to plot (hopefully a fractal--but probably not) with this information.